# UIBackgroundModes key not showing in Info.plist dropdown

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, info.plist

I am trying to upgrade an older iPhone project to adopt background audio streaming, however the "Required background modes" key is not showing up in the Info.plist drop-down menu.

I have set the base SDK to 4.0.  Is there another project setting that governs which Info.plist keys are available?

Kind regards,

Rob

Answer (score 14):

Open Info.plist as Plain text file and add:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the plist as a text file and enter the key yourself.

Comment: Thanks tob.  That's what I ended up doing, but I'm still very curious to know why certain keys aren't showing up in the drop-down menu.